# Android debugging switch between user and kernel modes

Tags: gdb, kernel, qemu, ida

Ok, I'm debugging in user mode, using GDB, IDA, w/e.
I'm also debugging in kernel mode, using GDB over QEMU.
How on earth do I mix the two?!

What I mean is, if for example I'm debugging a user mode service using GDB or IDA I can only stay in user space, plus this causes several issues, since the debug server itself is in user mode too, hooked over the debugged process, which causes conflicts with interrupts, timers and other processes, which usually leads to halt signals.

On the other hand, if I'm debugging in kernel mode using QEMU GDB, the entire system is at my disposal, which is great, however I'm unable to step into user mode/virtual space/etc.

Combining the two debugging methods in paralel doesn't seem to be helpful since the user mode debugger won't move when the kernel mode debugger is on break, and when the kernel debugger is on release I'm back to square one with user mode debugging issues.

Thoughts?

Comment: One thought I had was to add user space/virtual memory/etc support into the kernel debugger. Doable?